# how I convert string to float?

Tags: ros, arduino, python, ros-kinetic, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using arduino to send values from 0.00 to 5.00 and I'm trying to read them but I get this error

raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'x: "0.92"

this is the code, how can I convert the value to float?

```
def __init__(self): 
rospy.init_node('my_tf_broadcaster')
self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
    self.get_odometry()

def get_odometry(self):
self.pub_tf = rospy.Publisher("/tf", tf.msg.tfMessage)
    change = 0.0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            # Run this loop at about 10Hz
            rospy.sleep(0.1)
    
    message = self.ser.readline()       
    t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
    t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        t.header.frame_id = "odom"
        t.child_frame_id = "base_link"
        t.transform.translation.x = message.rstrip()    #trying to read this value
        t.transform.translation.y = 1.0
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.x = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.y = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.z = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0
    tfm = tf.msg.tfMessage([t])
        self.pub_tf.publish(tfm)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300350/how-i-convert-string-to-float?/) by [basicrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/36953/basicrobots/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a ROS question, but a Python one and you should have asked this on a more suitable forum (ie: one dedicated to Python development). Could you please review the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) next time before you post?

In any case: the Python `float(..)` function accepts strings and will try to parse them for you, so passing whatever `message.rstrip()` returns to `float(..)` should work.

---

Edit:

> when writing 'x: "0.92"

if you really write `x: "0.92"` on the serial prompt (or whatever program you're using for that), then that will not work, as `float(..)` will not be able to parse that.

And whatever `self.ser.readline()` returns is not a simple float, but the actual string `x: "0.92"`.

As that is not a `float`, the ROS msg serialiser cannot deal with that and returns you the error.

Again: not a problem with ROS, but with the way you're setting the values for the message fields.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
Note: indenting for your code is incorrect here, leading to only `rospy.sleep(0.1)` being executed as part of the `while` loop.

**Comment by [basicrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/36953/basicrobots/) on 2018-08-12**:
correct in python I can just do float(..) and it would work, but ROS when it grabs the values puts  ""  quotation marks and that's what's throwing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
`float(..)` will parse strings, so I'm not sure what you are saying.

For me, something like: `float('1.0')` returns a valid `float` value.